# Gitlab-ci runner : how to perform operations before cloning the repository

Tags: gitlab-ci-runner

I wonder if it is possible to perform some operations **before** the repository is cloned. Indeed, as far as I know, gitlab-ci runner first action is to clone the repository to be built before any  *script* can execute.

My problem:

- To build my project (let's call it **my plugin**) I need to clone another specific repository, let's call it **workspace**, and then I need to perform some operations to configure this **workspace** (using cmake).
- Once done, I need to put my project into a specific subfolder of the **workspace**, for instance in *workspace folder*/plugins/*my plugin*.
- Then I just have to configure **my plugin** (using cmake) and build/test (using different make commands).

The intuitive way to do that would be to be able to perform early operations before **my plugin** is cloned by the runner. For instance something like:

- cd builds/*namespace*/*my plugin*
- git clone *"git address of workspace"*
- cd workspace && cmake . -D"*some definitions*"
- cd plugins

=> from here the clone / build / test can proceed as usual.

I know there is the *before_script* action, but it is performed **after** clone.

I also see that there is the **pre_clone_script** option in the [[runner]] section of the global config.toml file of a runner and I wonder if I can use it for this. Unfortunately, it would imply that all projects will run this script what is certainly not a good idea...

Well If anyone has a suggestion, or better a nice solution to this problem, I would greatly appreciate !

Comment: Well finally I managed the build differently.

Comment: Sure wish you shared how you built it differently for anybody in the same situation.

Answer (score 6):

**Since Gitlab 16** the `pre_clone_script` feature is *deprecated* in favor of `pre_get_sources_script` hook.

See https://about.gitlab.com/blog/2023/03/27/changes-to-the-preclonescript/ and https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/configuration/advanced-configuration.html#the-runners-section

The documentation says:

`pre_clone_script`  *DEPRECATED - use pre_get_sources_script instead.*

`pre_get_sources_script` *Commands to be executed on the runner before updating the Git repository and updating submodules. Use it to adjust the Git client configuration first, for example.*

Answer (score 2):

I know the question is old, but right now https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/configuration/advanced-configuration.html#the-runners-section mentions `pre_clone_script` but that requires modifying *gitlab* configuration